# Как сделать так, чтобы RecyclerView не заезжал под элемент bottom navigation bar?

Tags: android, xml, android-fragment, recyclerview, bottom-navigation-view

Есть разметка фрагмента:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".presentation.Tabs.Medications.Medicine">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/catalogMedications"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

</layout>
```

В приложении используется `bottom navigation bar`. Проблема заключается в том, что нижний элемент находится наполовину под `bottom navigation bar`,так как у `RecyclerView` `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`. Можно, конечно, сделать `RecyclerView` фиксированного размера в `dp`, но тогда, скорее всего, на разных устройствах это будет выглядить очень по разному (и на некоторых `RecyclerView` всё равно будет заезжать под `bottom navigation bar`)

Разметка `activity`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".presentation.MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                android:id="@+id/sectTopMainMenu"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="13.1">

                <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                        android:id="@+id/topMainMenu"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                        android:background="@color/purple_700"
                        app:title="@string/app_name"
                        app:titleTextColor="@color/white"
                        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"/>

                </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

            </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/mainContent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

        <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

            <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/bottomMainMenu"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/purple_700"
                android:elevation="16dp"
                app:itemIconTint="@color/tab_color"
                app:itemTextColor="@color/tab_color"
                app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"/>

        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

Comment: покажите пожалуйста разметку родительской активности

Comment: @Andrew, добавил в вопрос

Comment: FrameLayout под CoordinationLayout. LinearLayout удаляете. CoordinatorLayout BottomNavigationView'а удаляете. CoordinatorLayout с AppBarLayout и BottomNavigationView будут под одним ConstrainLayout. У CoordinationLayout добавляете app:layout_constraintBotton_toTopOf="тут id нижней навигации".